# background-color com animação e pulso

Tags: javascript, css

Olá! Boa tarde.
Estou tentando provocar o seguinte efeito:
ao passar o mouse por cima de uma tag "a", o background-color da div pai na qual esta tag "a" é filha, possa mudar em transição mas num formato circular aonde este círculo partiria da tag "a" e se expandiria até atingir toda a div. É como uma transição gradiente radial do background-color.

Pensei em criar um elemento circular invisível de cor branca como pai da tag "a" mas filha da div maior. A estrutura seria:

```
<main>
  <article>
    <div class="box-de-texto" id="div-servicos">

     <p>texto...<p>
      <circle>
       <a>clique aqui</a>
      </circle>
     <p> mais texto>

    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

No CSS, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
#div-servicos {
    transition: all 150ms ease;

}

circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

e no Js:

```
var a = document.getElementById("aLink");
var div = document.getElementById("div-servicos");
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");

$(a).on("mouseover", function(){
    div.setAttribute("style","background-color: rgba(20,94,69,1.00); color: white;");
    circle.setAttribute("style","transform: scale(25); background-color: white;");
});
```

Com isso, eu consegui criar o efeito de:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O grande problema é que mesmo colocando o atributo "transform: scale(25)" no Js, parece que ele não está funcionando no "círculo" que criei.

O problema está quase resolvido e consegui inserir uma mudança na cor do texto contido dentro da tag "p" quando ocorre a animação mas acho que precisarei jogar a tag "p" para frente da camada da div de classe ripple (de acordo com a sugestão do comentário abaixo).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074246/how-to-create-ripple-effect-on-click-material-design#37500979) do SOen:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // MAD-RIPPLE // (jQ+CSS)
  $("[data-ripple]").hover(function(e) {
    
    var $self = $(this.parentNode);
    var $color = $(this).data("ripple");
    
    if($self.is(".btn-disabled")) {
      return;
    }
    if($self.closest("[data-ripple]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    var initPos = $self.css("position"),
        offs = $self.offset(),
        x = e.pageX - offs.left,
        y = e.pageY - offs.top,
        dia = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 100), // start diameter
        $ripple = $('<div/>', {class : "ripple",appendTo : $self });
    
    if(!initPos || initPos==="static") {
      $self.css({position:"relative"});
    }
    
    $('<div/>', {
      class : "rippleWave",
      css : {
        background: $color,
        width: dia,
        height: dia,
        left: x - (dia/2),
        top: y - (dia/2),
      },
      appendTo : $ripple
    });
  }, function(e) {
    $('div.ripple').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
/* No hover das tags com o atributo data-ripple, as tags p "do lado" ficam com a cor definida */
[data-ripple]:hover + p {
  color: red;
}

/* MAD-RIPPLE EFFECT */
.ripple{
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* to contain zoomed ripple */
  transform: translateZ(0);
  border-radius: inherit; /* inherit from parent (rounded buttons etc) */
  pointer-events: none; /* allow user interaction */
          animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
}
.rippleWave{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  opacity: 0.45;
          animation: ripple 5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 5s forwards;
}
@keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(999);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(999);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>Click to Ripple</h1>
  <a data-ripple="rgba(0,0,0,1)">data-ripple</a>
  <p>More text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Click to Ripple</h1>
  <a data-ripple="rgba(0,255,0,0.5)">data-ripple</a>
  <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Me ajudou bastante! Muito obrigado!
mas só uma dúvida: eu preciso que o texto da tag "p" dentro da div fique de cor branca para dar contraste com o background verde, provocado pelo evento. Daí eu acrescentei dentro do JS uma linha: $divServicos.setAttribute("style","color: rgba(255,255,255, 1); "); sendo essa variável $divServicos referente a div que é pai da tag "p". O texto fica em branco mas parece que essa div  de classe ripple fica na frente da div que contém o texto.

Comment: Mas pelo que entendi do código, essa div de classe ripple tem position absolute daí ela vai ficar por cima mesmo... então talvez fosse mais fácil tentar inserir uma tag "p" com o texto ja´de cor branca, dentro da construção da div de classe ripple, no código JS. o que acha?

Comment: Alías, retiro o que eu disse. Se eu colocar o texto pra ficar preto, ele fica. O branco que está sumindo lol

Comment: Não entendi direito, olha e dição que fiz no início do css, é o que quer?

Comment: Sim, você entendeu o que eu quero. Seria alterar a cor do texto dentro da tag "p" quando ocorrer o mouseover nesse atributo data-ripple. Mas não funcionou com a mudança "[data-ripple]:hover + p {
  color: red;
}"

Comment: olha o final edit

Comment: O que não funcionou? Lembrando que o evento `mouseover` é quando o mouse "entra" no elemento e o `mouseleave` quando o mouse "sai de cima" do elemento, o `hover` é enquanto o mouse está sobre o elemento

Comment: preciso que ocorra uma mudança de cor no texto da tag "e" quando ocorre o evento de mouseover na tag "a". Consegui criar isso inserindo essa mudança dentro da função que é chamada no hover mas parece que a div que é criada, fica na frente do texto, o que tampa ele um pouco.

Comment: postei uma imagem no edit

Comment: Acredito que deva fazer outra pergunta, colocando o seu código completo como ficou, não consigo saber qual o problema só pela imagem

Comment: criei uma nova pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320271/trazendo-a-tag-p-para-frente-de-uma-div