# trazendo a tag <p> para frente de uma div

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
 $("[data-ripple]").hover(function(e) {
    
    var $self = $(this.parentNode);
    var $color = $(this).data("ripple");
 var $divServicos = document.getElementById("div-servicos");
  
    
    if($self.is(".btn-disabled")) {
      return;
    }
    if($self.closest("[data-ripple]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    var initPos = $self.css("position"),
        offs = $self.offset(),
        x = e.pageX - offs.left,
        y = e.pageY - offs.top,
        dia = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 100), // start diameter
        $ripple = $('<div/>', {class : "ripple",appendTo : $self });
    
    if(!initPos || initPos==="static") {
      $self.css({position:"relative"});
    }
    
    $('<div/>', {
      class : "rippleWave",
      css : {
        background: $color,
        width: dia,
        height: dia,
        left: x - (dia/2),
        top: y - (dia/2),
      },
      appendTo : $ripple
    });
  $divServicos.setAttribute("style","color: rgba(255,255,255, 1); background-color: rgba(20,94,69,1.00);");
  var texto = $($self).html();
        texto = texto.substr(0, texto.indexOf('<a'));
        $(".ripple").append(texto);
  }, function(e) {
  $('div.ripple').remove();
  document.getElementById("div-servicos").setAttribute("style","color: green");
  });
```

```css
.div-secao {
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.box-content-informacoes{
 margin: 100px auto 5px auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "passion-one";
 color: #1A7F5F;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 30px;
 transition: max-height 250ms ease;
 max-height: auto;
}

#div-servicos {
 transition: all 150ms ease;
 
}
#h1Servicos {
 font-size: 60px;
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
}

.ripple{
 position: absolute;
 top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* to contain zoomed ripple */
 transform: translateZ(0);
 border-radius: inherit; /* inherit from parent (rounded buttons etc) */
 pointer-events: none; /* allow user interaction */
    animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
 -webkit-animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
}
.rippleWave{
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
 background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
 opacity: 0.6;
    animation: ripple 4s forwards;
 -webkit-animation: ripple 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {transform: scale(999);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(999);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<main>
<article class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">

<main class="div-secao" id="SecaoServicos">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <article>
    <div class="box-content-informacoes" id="div-servicos">
     <br>
     <h1 id="h1Servicos">Problemas com seu <strong>negócio? </strong>Podemos te ajudar!</h1>
     <p id="pFonte">Precisa de um rumo no seu negócio, mas ainda não sabe o caminho certo a seguir? Quer divulgar o seu empreendimento e aumentar o seu número de clientes? Ou não tem interesse em negócios, mas é louco para fazer aquele projeto da sua casa dos sonhos que nunca coube no seu bolso? Necessita de novas tecnologias que auxiliem no seu desenvolvimento profissional e pessoal? Entende a importância de projetos de engenharia pra você hoje, mas não consegue pagar? Nós temos a solução para você! Conheça melhor nossos serviços cicando <a id="aLink" data-ripple="rgba(20,94,69,1.00)" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBk1Xrp1j5zxZaftt_Fr1r_YMUPpELwE/view?usp=sharing"><strong>aqui</strong></a>     
     </p>
    </div>
   </article>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>

</article>
</main>
</body>
```

O que preciso resolver é o seguinte:

Quando o evento hover acontece, uma div de classe ripple é criada com a posição absolute para que sobreponha a div nativa do código HTML. o Mesmo texto dessa div nativa é inserido dentro dessa div de classe ripple. Além disso, uma segunda div é criada de classe ripple-wave que tem como objetivo, criar essa animação de ondulação se expandindo por toda a div. O texto contigo na tag "p" dentro da div nativa, precisa aparecer sem nenhum tipo de transparência, na frente dessa div de classe ripple-wave.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse "Clique aqui" na imagem é o mesmo que o `<a id="aLink" data-ripple="rgba(20,94,69,1.00)" href="url"><strong>aqui</strong></a>` do código?

Comment: é sim! é o mesmo

Comment: Veja se a resposta atende.

Comment: amigo, comentei sua resposta! Ajudou mas ainda está dando um efeito indesejado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o `@keyframes` para que o `background` da nova `div` fique transparente, e assim mostrando o texto abaixo:

```js
$("[data-ripple]").hover(function(e) {
    var $self = $(this.parentNode);
    var $color = $(this).data("ripple");
 var $divServicos = document.getElementById("div-servicos");

    if($self.is(".btn-disabled")) {
      return;
    }
    if($self.closest("[data-ripple]")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    var initPos = $self.css("position"),
        offs = $self.offset(),
        x = e.pageX - offs.left,
        y = e.pageY - offs.top,
        dia = Math.min(this.offsetHeight, this.offsetWidth, 100), // start diameter
        $ripple = $('<div/>', {class : "ripple",appendTo : $self });
    
    if(!initPos || initPos==="static") {
      $self.css({position:"relative"});
    }
    

    $('<div/>', {
      class : "rippleWave",
      css : {
        background: $color,
        width: dia,
        height: dia,
        left: x - (dia/2),
        top: y - (dia/2),
      },
      appendTo : $ripple
    });
  $divServicos.setAttribute("style","color: rgba(255,255,255, 1); background-color: rgba(20,94,69,1);");
  var pFonte = document.getElementById("pFonte");

  }, function(e) {
  $('div.ripple').remove();
  document.getElementById("div-servicos").setAttribute("style","color: green");
  });
```

```css
body{
   background: red;
}

.div-secao {
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.box-content-informacoes{
 margin: 100px auto 5px auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "passion-one";
 color: #1A7F5F;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 30px;
 transition: max-height 250ms ease;
 max-height: auto;
}

#div-servicos {
 transition: all 150ms ease;
 
}
#h1Servicos {
 font-size: 60px;
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
}

.ripple{
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* to contain zoomed ripple */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    border-radius: inherit; /* inherit from parent (rounded buttons etc) */
    pointer-events: none; /* allow user interaction */
          animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ripple-shadow 0.4s forwards;
    z-index: 2;
}

.rippleWave{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.7); -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    opacity: 0.7;
          animation: ripple 4s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ripple 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-shadow {
  0%   {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
  20%  {box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
  100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);}
}
@keyframes ripple {
  50% {
     background: transparent;
     }
  100% {
     transform: scale(999);
     background: transparent;
     }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  50% {
     background: transparent;
     }
  100% {
     transform: scale(999);
     background: transparent;
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<article class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">

<main class="div-secao" id="SecaoServicos">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <article>
<div class="box-content-informacoes" id="div-servicos">
               <span>
     <br>
     <h1 id="h1Servicos">Problemas com seu <strong>negócio? </strong>Podemos te ajudar!</h1>
     <p id="pFonte">Precisa de um rumo no seu negócio, mas ainda não sabe o caminho certo a seguir? Quer divulgar o seu empreendimento e aumentar o seu número de clientes? Ou não tem interesse em negócios, mas é louco para fazer aquele projeto da sua casa dos sonhos que nunca coube no seu bolso? Necessita de novas tecnologias que auxiliem no seu desenvolvimento profissional e pessoal? Entende a importância de projetos de engenharia pra você hoje, mas não consegue pagar? Nós temos a solução para você! Conheça melhor nossos serviços cicando <a id="aLink" data-ripple="rgba(20,94,69,1.00)" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBk1Xrp1j5zxZaftt_Fr1r_YMUPpELwE/view?usp=sharing"><strong>aqui</strong></a>     
     </p>
               </span>
    </div>
               </article>
  </div>
 </div>
</main>

</article>
```

Comment: Não só resolveu como ainda meu deu ideia de fazer algumas modificações pra incluir também uma mudança na tag h1. haha. Valeu mesmo, mano! Abraço